# Can I use an aviation radio on the ground in an emergency?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications, plane-spotting

Suppose I'm doing some plane spotting, and I see a dangerous situation that I think needs to be brought to the attention of a pilot or ATC (such as [a tire falling off an airplane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmahn2TlK4), an engine fire, etc.). I have a handheld aviation radio tuned, so I know that nobody's reported it. Would it be permissible for me to use that radio to call it in? How would I identify myself since I'm not in a plane and therefore have no tail number? Would I have to identify myself at all?

Comment: One problem you face is that you do not have a radio license that permits you to transmit on that band.  In many countries, these license are explicitly granted to pilots.  In the U.S., I believe radio licenses are usually implicitly granted along with the pilot's license.  But you have to have one (legally).

Comment: Pilots operating domestically in the USA are exempt from FCC permitting/licensing, it is an exemption not an implicit license. US pilots must obtain an FCC radio operators permit before flying internationally. The aircraft itself may have some station license requirements, but I am not an owner so never looked into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, and should, use any means necessary to render assistance that might be needed in an emergency and not worry about lack of an FCC ground station license stopping you. However, good judgement is needed to discern the severity, level of help needed or wanted, and the value your transmission might provide.

For example, I would be extremely reluctant to key the mic on a heavy Airbus at a major airport on tower freq if they are trailing a little smoke because it's likely they have cockpit indications already, and you'd probably get a whole lot of unwanted attention afterwards.  But if I were at a small rural non-towered field on Unicom I wouldn't hesitate for a second to transmit "Bonanza on final, your right main gear is NOT down!"

I can't speak as to how the FCC might view your actions, but knowing that the CFRs allow a PIC to deviate from any regulation to the extent needed to meet the emergency, and that many states have Good Samaritan laws to protect people from being persecuted for helping others in distress, I would rather have a clear conscience and take action in good faith than cower in the face of potential repercussions.

Oh, to answer your last question, (and to mitigate those FCC repercussions...) I would probably just NOT identify myself.  ;)

Comment: The FCC would actually not smile on this at all.  (I’m also a lm amateur radio and commercial radio operator licensee.)  There was a case some time ago where a ham radio operator used his radio to make a bona fire emergency call on a frequency he was not licensed for.  He was revoked by the FCC and was ultimately convicted.  The court acknowledged that it was a bona fide emergency, but held that Good Samaritan doctrine did not apply.  No jail time, but his minor fine and license revocation were upheld.

Comment: @Max - That's your government in action...  Good to know, and a good reason to not identify yourself.  Personally I would give up a stupid license to save a life.  (especially if I was unlicensed to begin with!)

Comment: I agree with your original comment, one approach is to make the call and then not identify yourself.  Reminds me of that commercial, “This is Peggy.”  Here’s part of what makes this a hard call…  If I see a plane fall out of the sky, then I *know* this is an emergency and I *know* I have a moral justification, even if my license is at risk.  But a tire bouncing down a runway is a different calculus for a non pilot.  “WTH was that, WTH does that even mean, WTH did I just see?” is a harder starting position for taking a risky action.

Comment: @Max do you have a source for the "revoked after an emergency" story?

Comment: @Max given 47 CFR § 97.403 "Safety of life and protection of property.
No provision of these rules prevents the use by an amateur station of any means of radiocommunication at its disposal to provide essential communication needs in connection with the immediate safety of human life and immediate protection of property when normal communication systems are not available." you need a good source for that.

Comment: @JonCuster, That's a great reference.  You have first dibs for finding it, but if you don't post an answer yourself would you mind if I incorporated it into my answer?

Comment: @MichaelHall - feel free. I would point out that that is under the amateur rules, not aviation rules. Amateur is part 97, aviation is part 87. I see "§ 87.397 Emergency operations.

(a) The licensee of any land station in the Aviation services, during a local emergency involving the safety of life and property may communicate in a manner other than that specified in the license" which is quite different - the OP would need to be a licensee even in an emergency?

Comment: I can’t find a specific source, it would have been 1991 or 92, because I remember the meeting where we discussed the implications of this.  It seemed like a no-brainer to me.  This was an amateur whose 2m handheld was capable of transmitting on public safety bands in the 150MHz range.  He called a police dispatcher directly as a result of an accident.  His club repeater also had autopatch, and he was within coverage.  It was held that he had another means.  97.405 relaxes the “other means” requirement if the station itself is “in distress”…  (cont)

Comment: But 97.403, reporting on behalf of the public safety or safety of others, has an elevated standard of “normal communication systems are not available.”  It seemed insane to us that he was cited, but it was noteworthy enough that the ARRL sent a communication out about it and we discussed that communication at our club meeting, that’s how I remember the timeframe.  There are many, many things in life that you can do 100 times…  90 times no one cares, 9 times someone escalates it but it ultimately blows over…  and one time in 100 the snake bites.

Comment: Given all the comments and other references maybe it's better to leave as-is.  As a general rule regulatory bodies have jurisdiction over licensees, and enforcement actions are limited to revocation of licenses for failing to adhere to the terms of the "contract".  Which is motivation enough for those interested in keeping their license.  However, I think it would require a higher legal standard for an agency to pursue criminal action against an unlicensed individual, and they would probably have to prove negligence or that harm was done.  But that's a better question for Law SE.